# How exactly do I calculate this correlation function?

Tags: research-level, scattering, correlation-functions

I found a research paper (from 1977) that has a particular equation I need to reproduce. The paper essential calculates dynamic light scattering correlation functions.

The full equations I need to work out is this:

$$
f(q,\tau) = \frac{\int_{-1}^{+1}(1-2w^2\nu^2) \exp(-w^2\nu^2)\ d\nu \times \int_{0}^{2\pi} A[q,\mu(t)]A^*[q,\mu(0)]\ d\psi}{\int_{0}^{2\pi} |A[q,\mu(0)]|^2\ d\psi}
$$

Essentially I need to calculate this for values of the delay time $t$. The bit I am not sure how to do is the  $\int_{0}^{2\pi} A[q,\mu(t)]A^*[q,\mu(0)]\ d\psi$. The actual functional form of A isn't that important, but it consists of spherical Bessel functions and the term $\psi$ which is to be numerically integrated over.

Now, where I am stuck is what do I actually do to calculate that function for the delay times. I have tried a lot of things but I just cant get it looking like they have in the paper. Here is what I have tried:

- Calculate $\int_{0}^{2\pi} A[q,\mu(t)]$ for all delay times, and then use a built in autocorrelation function to obtain the results.
- Take my first $t$ value (say 0.01 sec), and my second $t$ value (say 0.02 sec) and then calculate $\int_{0}^{2\pi} A[q,\mu(0.02)]A^*[q,\mu(0.01)]\ d\psi$... etc for all t values (so $t0$ lags 1 behind t.
- A few other things.

As you can see I am a bit confused, if anyone has any insight as to how I would calculate this by hand that would be extremely helpful.

---

#### Edit:

The full functional form of $A(q,\mu(t))$ is 
$$
A(q,\mu(t))\propto \frac{3j_1(u)}{u} + F^3 \frac{m_2-m_1}{m_1-1}\frac{3j_1(f u)}{fu}
%Old version: \frac{F^3 (m_2-m_1) (3 j_1(F \mu(t)))}{(m_1-1) (F \mu(t))}+\frac{3 j_1(\mu(t))}{\mu(t)}
$$
where $j_1$ is a spherical Bessel function of the first kind, $u=q\sqrt{a^2\mu^2(t)+b^2(1-\mu^2(t))}$, $F=1-\frac ta$, and $\mu(t)=\cos(\psi)\sin(\theta)\sin(\alpha(t))+\cos(\theta)\cos(\alpha(t))$, for $\nu=\cos(\theta)$ and $\alpha(t)=\omega t+\phi$.

Yes, I am after $f$ vs $t$ for a $q$ of my choice. I am just not sure I am computing the integral properly for the values of $t$.

For example, lets say my $t$ of interest was $0.1, 0.2,0.4, 0.8, 1.6$ (just an example).

For the very first $t$, would I simply do,

$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}A[q,\mu(0.2)]\times A[q,\mu(0.1)]
$$

Then for the next $t$

$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}A[q,\mu(0.4)]\times A[q,\mu(0.1)]
$$

or

$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}A[q,\mu(0.4)]\times A[q,\mu(0.2)]
$$

And dont I need to average over the same delay time $\tau$? So for $\tau 1$ its

$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}A[q,\mu(0.2)]\times A[q,\mu(0.1)]\\
\int_{0}^{2\pi}A[q,\mu(0.4)]\times A[q,\mu(0.2)]\\
\int_{0}^{2\pi}A[q,\mu(0.8)]\times A[q,\mu(0.4)]\\
\int_{0}^{2\pi}A[q,\mu(1.6)]\times A[q,\mu(0.8)]
$$.

I am using Mathematica to evaluate these functions.

As you can see I am rather confused. Thanks so much for your help. The paper I am referencing is:

> Rotational—translational models for interpretation of quasi-elastic light scattering spectra of motile bacteria. Michael Holz and Sow-Hsin Chen. [*Appl. Optics* **17** no. 20, pp. 3197-3204 (1978)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1364/AO.17.003197).

Comment: What is the dependence of $A$ relatively to $\psi$ ?

Comment: Hi, $\psi$ is an averaging term. The actual A is equal to the following (simplified the constants): $\frac{3j_{1}(u)}{u}$, where $u = q(a^2\mu^2(t)+b^2(1-\mu^2(t))^{(1/2)}$. $q$ is a constant, so is $a$ and $b$. $\mu(t) = cos(\psi)sin(\theta)sin(\alpha(t))+cos(\theta)cos(\alpha(t))$

Comment: oops, didn't know about the 5 minute comment time out. And finally $\alpha(t) = (\omega*t+\phi)$. All terms except $\psi$ and $t$ are constants. Its a bit messy but I have it all in a mathematica worksheet. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the integration over $\psi$ must be done numerically, then there is most likely very little you can do to simplify this expression. The prefactor
$$
\frac{\int_{-1}^{+1}(1-2w^2\nu^2) \exp(-w^2\nu^2)\ d\nu }{\int_{0}^{2\pi} |A[q,\mu(0)]|^2\ d\psi}
$$
you can compute once for each $q$, and then you can forget about it as you vary $\tau$ (which I presume is identical to $t$).

The main bit of your integral, though,
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} A[q,\mu(\tau)]A^*[q,\mu(0)]\ d\psi,$$
will probably need to be computed numerically for each time $\tau$ of interest. If you post more details on the functional dependence of $A$ on $q$, $\mu$ and $\psi$ (and of $\mu$ on $t$) then it may be possible to find a simpler method which simplifies the integration and even allows you to integrate numerically only once, but this is not possible in general, and quite unlikely as a rule.

Other than that, it depends on what you want to know about $f(q,t)$. If all you want is graphs of $f$ as a function of $t$ for a few values of $q$, then you're essentially asking for the values of $f$ on a grid of times $\tau_0,\tau_0+\delta \tau,\ldots,\tau_1-\delta \tau,\tau_1$, and each of these must be computed separately by numerically integrating (1). If you want more sophisticated information on $f$ then... well, it depends.

---

Regarding the averaging over initial times:

Typically, autocorrelation functions of the form $$C(\tau)=C(t,t')=\left\langle c^\ast(t)c(t')\right\rangle$$
are formally and explicitly independent of time translation, so $C(t+t'',t'+t'')=C(t,t')\,\forall t'$ and they can be reduced to a function of $\tau=t-t'$. In this case the formal time translation invariance has been lost, probably by enforcing initial conditions at $t'=0$, which means that here you **should not** change the $t'=0$ inside $A^\ast$ to other times (generally you don't need to, but it doesn't hurt). Take the products $A(q,\mu(t))A^\ast(q,\mu(0))$ as you've been given and don't tamper with them.

Comment: I have updated my original post. Thank you very much for your time. I am trying to reproduce the graphs they get with the same values, to verify I have performed the calculations properly.

Comment: So if I understand, first I should work out $A(q,\mu(t))$ for an array of $t's$ ($A$), then set $t = 0$, work out the new $A(q,\mu(t))$ (just comes out as one number, $A0$). I am pretty sure that is what I have done in mathematica. 
I then execute $$\frac{\text{NIntegrate}[\text{A} \times \text{A0},\{\psi ,0,2 \pi \}]}{\text{NIntegrate}\left[2 \left| \text{A0}\right| ^2,\{\psi ,0,2 \pi \}\right]}$$ with the normalization prefactor.
This current code seems to work for certain $\theta$'s, but then blows up with a huge oscillation at others. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Yes, that's about correct. I don't know what would cause divergences in this, but the standard methods apply. Graph the integrand as a function of $\psi$ for the problematic regions: is it actually divergent? If so, why?

Comment: Thanks again, I am not quite sure what you mean by graph the integrand as a function of $\psi$. The integral seems to work at $90°$, but diverges at $19°$. I would post a picture if I could. I also don't quite understand how they did this in 1978 and I am struggling so much lol

Comment: Hmm, I think I know what you mean. Plotting just the integrand at $90°$ shows it starting at its maximum value and then it decays and oscillates like its supposed to. But at $19°$ it stays at its lowest value then shoots upwards, that would be the cause for the huge bump I am getting. Still not sure why, I should be able to calculate this at any $\theta$, and it should decay from 1 to 0...

Comment: Well, what is $\psi$ at the divergence? What is $\mu$? What is $u$? Are you dividing by zero? If so, are you explicitly telling MM to handle this?

Comment: There is no division by zero. $u$ and $\mu$ are just those values given. I am not sure what you mean by what is $\psi$ at the divergence.I am calculating the integral between $\psi = 0$ and $2\pi$ once at $\theta = 90°$ and then all I change is $\theta = 19°$.

Comment: @SteveHatcher $u$ and $\mu$ depend on $\psi$. I am recommending you _look at the graph of your integrand_ before you demand correct answers from your computer. What does $A(q,\mu(t))A^\ast(q,\mu(0))$ _look like_, as a function of $\psi$, before you integrate? How does the behaviour change from well-behaved $\theta$s through to ill-behaved ones?

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it now. When I plot the graph of just $A(q,\mu(t))A^*(q,\mu(0))$ for a fixed $\psi$ I can see the graph either starts low and shoots up with rapid oscillations, or starts high and shoots down with rapid oscillations, or starts in the middle and turns into them (at later $\tau$) as I vary $\theta$. So I guess I have nailed it down to the problem, but I am really at a loss as to how to fix this. Thanks again for your help

Comment: @SteveHatcher OK. I would fix $\theta$ and $\tau$ and look at the graph with respect to $\psi$ - but whatever works for you, works.

Comment: oh, I understand what you mean now, I will give that a go. Thanks.